# Contact Form 7 ошибки в консоли

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть такая проблема. Иногда не срабатывает форма на сайте , то-есть при нажатии «Отправить» , в консоли браузера появляются ошибки:

1. failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
2. failed to load /wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/638/feedback

Но когда заходишь в админку и чистишь кеш(WP Fastest Cache) , то проблем с отправкой нет, но через время опять появляются ошибки.

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и как её можно решить??

Answer (score 0):

Формы в WordPress и правильных плагинах, вроде Contact Form 7, защищаются скрытыми полями [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) - Number Used Once. На самом деле nonce не совсем одноразовые, а имеют время жизни - по умолчанию два тика по 12 часов.

Ответ 403 означает, что nonce просрочен. Так происходит из-за жёсткого кеширования страницы плагинами страничного кеширования, например, WP Fastest Cache. Установите срок жизни кеша в настройках плагина меньше, чем время одного тика nonce. Т.е., обычно, менее 12 часов.